# How to get the link to raw data of a file on Cloud Storage?

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, arcore, gltf

Im currently developping an AR-core based app in which users can upload .gltf files to the Cloud firestore. To be able to render those 3D-models in runtime, I need to retrieve the link to the raw data, not a download link.

What I need is something like this:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/patrickbusser/patrickbusser/master/Lantern.gltf

So getDownloadUrl() won't be of any help I assume.

How can that be achieved for Android Studio with firebase?

Comment: What's the difference between a "link to the raw data" and a "download link"?  Why would a download URL not work?

Comment: With the example of the github-link, it directly shows the data, but doesnt download it, but when I try to access the file through Firestore, it downloads this file. Im very new to this, so sorry if my explanation is not very clear :(. I posted my code below, hopefully it makes things more clear.

Comment: I don't see why a github link is relevant here.  Why doesn't a **Firebase** download URL work?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Storage requires a token to be passed to an API endpoint which returns the raw data.

The problem you face is that your 3D object is in gltf format. This format, by default, references other files (textures, etc). So, when your app accesses the main gltf file with a token based URL it will also need to download the referenced files; each of which also requires a secure token.

I would suggest one of the following solutions:

1. Your app should  follow the token procedure for each referenced file within the main gltf thus downloading the main file and it's references files in raw format.
2. Use a gltf format that doesn't depend on referenced files. For example, the glb format is a binary version; you can also 'embed' the reference files using the uri/base64 format.
3. Use a CDN or web hosting instead of Firebase Storage. This way the referenced files will automatically resolve in the way that your app likely anticipated.